# AWS Kinesis PutRecordAsync on .NET - what data format should I use to publish IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-kinesis

I have a web socket returning *JSON* which is deserialized to `IEnumerable<Car>` by `System.Text.Json`.

```cs
public record Car(string Id, string Make, string Model);
```

What format should I use to publish `IEnumerable<Car>` into the stream?

Should I keep it as JSON or can I use Protobuf/MessagePack? The faster, the better.

```cs
public Task<PutRecordResponse> PublishAsync(string data, string partitionKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest
    {
        StreamName = _streamName,
        PartitionKey = partitionKey,
        Data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))
    };

    return _kinesisClient.PutRecordAsync(putRecordRequest, cancellationToken);
}

public Task<PutRecordsResponse> PublishAsync(IEnumerable<string> data, string partitionKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var putRecordsRequest = new PutRecordsRequest
    {
        StreamName = _streamName,
        Records = data.Select(d => new PutRecordsRequestEntry
        {
            Data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(d)),
            PartitionKey = partitionKey
        }).ToList()
    };

    return _kinesisClient.PutRecordsAsync(putRecordsRequest, cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I keep it as JSON or can I use Protobuf/MessagePack? The faster, the better.

Can you use something else other than JSON? Yes.

Should you? Most likely not.

**Leave it as JSON** unless you have confirmed, via performance benchmarking, that serialisation & deserialisation of one of the most widely used data formats - JSON - on one of the most widely used enterprise frameworks - .NET - is your performance bottleneck.

Practically, there will most likely be a negligible (if any) performance difference between JSON & Protobuf / MessagePack.

Any format that you can convert to & from the fastest and will produce the smallest output will be the "fastest" theoretically however this will need benchmarking on your side in a real-world environment.

The system is 99% likely slower in other parts...